# $Q$-value definition checking

Tags: nuclear-physics

Consider a nuclear reaction being going on which is $$A +B -> C + D ,$$ is it true that $Q$-values which is defined to be difference in the masses energy from reactants to products. Will give us the energy released/absorbed (exothermic/endothermic reactions)? As such what i think it should be the difference in total energy when converting from reactants to products which will include their kinetic energies too then that definition if true will makes sense isnt? (That will tell that how much energy released/absorbed, the total energy difference) [If the reactants were having some initial kinetic energy, as the $Q$-value formula is the difference in  just the rest masses, so the initial KE will not be included, so will not then the energy released or absorbed should be dependent in initial KE. Too hence the formula should be dependent on both KE and rest masses isnt?] as this gives the energy released/absorbed during the reaction.

Comment: Any energy released will be turned into kinetic energies of the products (or would be the input energy required to make the reaction happen).

Comment: @JonCuster  Okay thats fine but what about if the reactants were having intial kinetic energy , as the Q value formula is the difference in  rest masses , so the intial KE will not be included , so will not then the energy released or absorbed should be dependent in intial KE. Too hence the formula should be dependent on both KE and rest masses ?

Comment: No, the Q-value does not consider any other energy in the system. If there is additional kinetic energy, it has to be taken into consideration as well as the momentum in order to get the energies and momenta of the reactants.

Comment: Yeah that what i was saying , i mean as Q value means that **energy released/absorbed** 
in a reaction, so was thinking if it was valid even when intial KE is there too ( that is just the difference in just rest mass will give the required energy gain or loss ). So its not true right ? And so that definition of Q value being giving the energy absorbed /released only in case when initial KE is zero right ? @JonCuster

Comment: Do the reaction in the center-of-mass frame - it makes your life much easier...

Comment: I am just clearing concept in Q value , not problem solving , although def i will go with COM frame if needed @JonCuster